# Shall I restart both nginx and gunicorn when production is updated?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

What is the best practice when I have an update for my Django app pushed in my production? Shall I restart both `gunicorn` and `nginx` services, with

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

or restarting only `gunicorn` is enough? Finally does the order of the restarts makes any difference if I have to do both the restarts? Thanks!

Comment: I am using uWsgi and nginx and I do not restart none of them. I think you should not restart nginx unless you change its configuration files. And You probably want to reload unicorn (sending [HUP](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/signals.html) signal). I hope you get better answer soon.

Answer (score 6):

It entirely depends on how you've configured your box.

To keep downtime to an absolute minimum, I actually load my new release into a different directory on the box while the old release is still running. I create a new virtual environment based on my new release's requirements.txt. Then I start a second instance of gunicorn with the new release running in it (done via supervisord with entries in supervisord.conf), and leave the old instance still running.

I then update my nginx vhost file to point the server to the new release's gunicorn socket, and finally reload nginx. I do a quick check that the new site is up and functioning, and then I stop the old gunicorn instance. If for some reason it's not responding, I switch my nginx config back to point to the old one again, and then go figure out what's wrong.

I do all this using an Ansible script, but here's a great article with some Fabric scripts to do something similar: https://medium.com/@healthchecks/deploying-a-django-app-with-no-downtime-f4e02738ab06

If, on the other hand, you just update your code in-place, then there should be no changes needed to your nginx config, so you shouldn't need to reload it. Just reload gunicorn and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you Anna. Very nice approach! Thumbs up